# How to set datetime to Date.current everyday?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to figure out a model method that would make a `nil` deadline become `Date.current`?

I want the `deadline` to refresh to `Date.current` at the start of everyday.

### challenge.rb

```
def deadline_current
  self.deadline == Date.current  # How to trigger something like this at the start of each day and upon the creation of a new challenge?
end
```

Comment: Are you trying to update the `deadline` attribute for _all_ Challenge records to `Date.current`?

Comment: https://github.com/javan/whenever

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it correctly, the best approach in my opinion is to set a cron job to run every day. To do this I recommend using the gem [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever):

```
every 1.day, :at => '0:00 am' do
runner "Challenge.deadline_current"
end
```